# Automapper - Map model from lowercase to pascal case

Tags: c#, .net, regex, automapper, lowercase

I have two models.

Source model:

```
public sealed class adresse
{
        public string strasse { get; set; }
        public string hausnummer { get; set; }
        public string plz { get; set; }
        public string ort { get; set; }
        public string landCode { get; set; }
}
```

Destination model:

```
public sealed class Adresse
{
        public string Strasse { get; set; }
        public string Hausnummer { get; set; }
        public string Plz { get; set; }
        public string Ort { get; set; }
        public string LandCode { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore I created a mapping with automapper and a unit test.

```
public class AddressMapper
    {
        public Address map()
        {
            adresse add = new adresse();
            add.hausnummer = "1";
            add.ort = "Test";

            AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                cfg.AddProfile<Profile1>();
            });
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Address>(add);
        }
    }

public class LowerNamingConvention : INamingConvention
    {
        public Regex SplittingExpression
        {
            get { return new Regex(@"[\p{Ll}a-z A-Z 0-9]+(?=_?)"); }
        }

        public string SeparatorCharacter
        {
            get { return string.Empty; }
        }
    }

public class Profile1 : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerNamingConvention();
            DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
            CreateMap<adresse, Address>();
        }
    }



[TestFixture]
    public class AddressMapperTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMapper()
        {
            var sut = new AddressMapper();

            var value = sut.map();
        }
    }
```

When I'm running the test every field in the destination model is null.

As you can see there is a problem with the naming because some names in the source model I have some times different naming conventions like lower case or lower camel case. Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem? Or do I have to map everything manualy?

Comment: In the `map` method, you are mapping to the `Address` class not the `Adresse` class given in the example. Is that just a typo?

Comment: yes you are right. My mistake. However, the mapping for landCode ist still not working. Something with my RegEx is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a proper solution for my problem. Sorry for not being familar with Regex. I just combined the RegExes from

[AutoMapper/src/AutoMapper/PascalCaseNamingConvention.cs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/32959279d8b81087d1c84903f56755cc57d35740/src/AutoMapper/PascalCaseNamingConvention.cs)
and 
[AutoMapper/src/AutoMapper/LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention.cs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/32959279d8b81087d1c84903f56755cc57d35740/src/AutoMapper/LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention.cs)

into my own naming convention. Might be that there are cases wich can cause issues. But as far as I have tested it works.

```
public class LowerNamingConvention : INamingConvention
{
    public Regex SplittingExpression
    {
        get { return new Regex(@"[\p{Ll}0-9]+(?=$|\p{Lu}[\p{Ll}0-9])|\p{Lu}?[\p{Ll}0-9]+)"); }
    }

    public string SeparatorCharacter
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use DataContract and DataMember attributes as below, so that you don't need to give property a same name and also you can follow coding standards.

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class YourClass
    {
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "myVariable")]
        public string MyVariable { get; set; }
    }
```